# How to continue draw something on JPanel after clicked the button without repaint?

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I have define the `JPanel` named `drawPanel`, and a button named `Jbutton1` with an `ActionListener`. I want to continue draw something on the `drawPanel` after clicked the `Jbutton1`. And I do not want to clear the `drawPanel` first and draw more things, I just want to continue draw on the `drawPanel` and show it in a `JFrame`.

Comment: What does the button have to do with `repaint()`?  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two common ways to do this:

1. Keep a List of Objects that you want to paint and then iterated through the list every time.
2. Paint to a BufferedImage and then just paint the BufferedImage.